# Which is better, updating multiple rows using individual connections or using IN statement with large array?

Tags: c#, sql, database, postgresql, sql-update

I have a c# application that results in an array of 40K ids that correspond to records in a Postgres database.  I need to update the "completed" field to 'true' for each of those ids.  My question: Is it more efficient to do this 40K times:

```
foreach (i in ids[]){
conn.open()
UPDATE TABLE SET "completed" = true WHERE "id" = i
conn.close()
}
```

or this once with a 40K item int array:

```
conn.open()
UPDATE TABLE SET "completed" = true WHERE "id" IN (id[].Tostring())
conn.close()
```

Of course the above code is not proper c#, more of a way to illustrate my question of doing a series of 40K connections to the database or doing it with one connection and a single update that utilizes an IN statement and large size array.

Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: First you need to check if an IN clause supports a so long list of elements.

Comment: define "besser". i'd prefer option 2 in any case, but i'd _not_ provide a 40K heavy array. instead, i'd batch them in sets of 2000 or something.

Answer (score 3):

I will most probably be faster to execute one large query than many small queries. This limits the overhead in many ways such as network round trips to the server, query parsing, transaction management, and so on.

If you have a very large list of values, `in` might not be optimal, or even not functional. I would suggest `values()` instead:

```
update mytable as t
set completed = true 
from (values (1), (2), (3), ...) as v(id)  -- stuff all the values here
where t.id = v.id
```